# explain this OOPS cpnecpt in php ..i dont get the 2nd echo $a becomes 30

Tags: php, mysql

why is the $a in 2nd echo becomes 30 when its should be 20

---

```
 function &ref_return() {
            global $a;
            $a = $a * 2;
            return $a;
        }
        $a = 10;
        $b =& ref_return();

        echo "a: {$a} / b: {$b}<br />"; 


        $b = 30;
        echo "a: {$a} / b: {$b}<br />";
```

---

### OUTPUT:

a: 20 / b: 20
a: 30 / b: 30

Comment: *Side Note*: Nothing here relates to OOPS.

Comment: then how is the 2nd $a = 30 ?

Comment: Because both variables refer to the same value because you're using references...!?

Comment: since it is a matter of global and call by ref i concluded it as an OOPS thing

Comment: after $b=30....i havent called the $ref_return()....how come they are referred to the same value then ??????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$a` and `$b` are referencing the same address. You do this first by creating the [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
$b =& ref_return();
```

Now $a and $b are identically. When you next assign `$b = 30` this affects `$a` as well.

Comment: okay so in PHP if a variable is linked once.........it considers to be linked in the followong codes as well ???? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: unless you don't explicitly remove the reference with `unset()`, yes. BTW your "?" key seems to be broken.